# Rendering a form in a custom twig does not respect tag order

Tags: 8, forms

I have a small custom form that I am supplying a theme hook pointing to a custom template for. The weird thing is, it has all of the markup, but is not respecting it.

Here is the code in the form template being used:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function harlib_newsletter_signup_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $themes = [];

  $themes['newsletter_signup'] = [
    'render element' => 'form',
    'template' => 'form/newsletter-signup',
  ];

  return $themes;
}
```

Twig:

```
<section>
  <form{{ attributes.addClass('hl__single-input-form__form') }}>
    {{ form }}
  </form>
</section>
```

But here is the source, where it is out of order. The `section` tag is inside of the form tag instead of outside:

[image]

Also, why does this not add a class on the form tag?

```
<form{{ attributes.addClass('hl__single-input-form__form') }}>
```

I tried to also add it from the Form API itself with

```
$form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'hl__single-input-form__form';
```

When I do that, that class is added up to the parent `div` tag, the block that outputs the form.

The base theme is stable.

Form code:

```
$form['#theme'] = 'newsletter_signup';

$form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'hl__single-input-form__form';

$form['title'] = [
  '#type' => 'label',
  '#for' => 'edit-email-address',
  '#title' => 'Want to stay in the know?',
  '#attributes' => [
    'class' => [
      'hl__label',
      'hl__label--inline',
    ],
  ],
];

$form['email_address'] = [
  '#type' => 'email',
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#attributes' => [
    'placeholder' => $this->t('Email'),
    'class' => [
      'hl__input',
      'hl__input--inline',
      'js-is-required',
    ],
  ],
  '#prefix' => '<div class="hl__single-input-form__input-group">',
];

$form['submit'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => $this->t('Sign Up'),
  '#attributes' => [
    'class' => [
      'hl__button',
      'hl__button--small',
      'hl__button--inline',
    ],
  ],
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
];

return $form;
```

Comment: Yes, this looks weird. In the twig debug output you have `THEME HOOK: newsletter_signup`, but the template name is starting with `form__`. Normally the template name should always start with the theme hook.

Comment: That was on me - let me add my theme hook. I renamed the template file.

Comment: Now when you run the code again you should see two templates in the twig debug output, one for the outer form tag with the form attributes and one for the inner form elements in {{ form }}.

Comment: Ah, right you are. So I need to add a template suggestion alter for this instead to add more than one form suggestion?

Comment: You mean for the form tag `form__...`? Then yes, because this is in #theme_wrappers. When you add #theme to the form this generates a new template for the inner part of the form.